# How to make Chrome Extension using scraped data from other URLs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, request, browserify, cheerio

I want this to be an extension which I will use on my own and not share to any other party.

So, I am using request, cheerio and browserify through the node ecosystem, to let client-side mimic serverside. 
But of course, when I "upload" my extension to my own local chrome, it won't run because it simply not recognizes the 'require' keyword.

Any ideas on how I should proceed?

Comment: You need to compile/bundle the extension so that everything it uses is included within its package.

Comment: @wOxxOm I believe this will work BUT I put them unpackaged. cause if I package it then the chrome will not run the crx installed simply because it is not listed on the store and hence not trusted.

Comment: By "package" I meant the set of files that the extension consists of, not its CRX archive.

Comment: Oh, that's not working. 
const request = require('request'); is the error. it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase. Extensions run in the browser and as such they can't use node modules system directly. There should be compilers/bundlers that process require() calls and produce a local bundle that includes everything that the extension uses.

Comment: @wOxxOm That seems to be exactly my problem! :)
Any idea on how to solve it??

Comment: Personally I don't know the exact tools, but I told you what to look for. AFAIK this question was asked many times here on StackOverflow and elsewhere so hopefully you'll find an answer.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think there are some tools like such. I'll start with webpack! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Ok so everyone knows:

I used browserify which bundles everything together. The silly mistake of mine is that inside manifest.js of my chrome extension, I forgot to set the content_scripts to budle.js and had it to content.js

WRONG

```
"content_scripts": [{
"css": ["style.css"],
"js": ["content.js"],
```

CORRECT

```
"content_scripts": [{
"css": ["style.css"],
"js": ["bundle.js"],
```